# How to enable Auto USB Tethering in Android programmatically or using shell for Android 7 and higher

Tags: java, android, kotlin, root, su

I've tried different ways to do it:

1. Tried Connectivity Manager class which is deprecated by Android because it doesn't have a setUsbTethering method.
2. Tried this method:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

```
public void switchOnTethering() {

    Object obj = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (Method m : obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {

        if (m.getName().equals("tether")) {
            try {
                m.invoke(obj, "usb0");
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Tried adb shell service call connectivity 30,31,32,33,34 i32 1 command
4. Tried

```
adb shell
su
echo "rndis" > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions
echo "1" > /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable
```

5. Tried

```
adb shell
su
netcfg rndis0 up
netcfg rndis0 dhcp
```

6. The only thing that works for me Adb shell svc usb setFunctions rndis
   but it works only in Android 11

I need to make it for Android 7 and higher. It's okay if there is a way needs root because I have rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

In [Android 7.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-7.0.0_r1/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/UsbCommand.java#49) it was `adb shell svc usb setFunction rndis`

You can also try `adb shell setprop sys.usb.config rndis`

Comment: do you know which versions that accept SVC command? and if it is applicable on Huawei,Xiaomi,... or just on samsung devices ?

Comment: Tell me you did not click the link in my answer without telling me you didn't...